# Which tags are automatically added to per-site metas?

Tags: support, tags, per-site-meta

The four necessary tags ([discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [support](/questions/tagged/support)), plus the various moderator-only tags ([featured](/questions/tagged/featured), [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) et al), are presumably automatically included as tags on every per-site meta and not subject to the "automatic deletion of unused tags" algorithm.

I've noticed that other tags also seem to be given this special treatment. Some of the tags on meta.SFF have 0 questions to their name yet haven't disappeared, such as [openid](/questions/tagged/openid) and [login](/questions/tagged/login). I assume the same is true for often-used tags such as [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) and [tags](/questions/tagged/tags).

### What's the complete list of tags which are automatic on per-site metas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like the full set is:

- reputation
- site-promotion
- questions
- tags
- comments
- badges
- answers
- search
- voting
- editing
- bounty
- user-interface
- specific-question
- accepted-answer
- markdown
- stackexchange
- community-wiki
- down-votes
- openid
- migration
- vote-to-close
- exact-duplicates
- etiquette
- notifications
- users
- closed-questions
- hyperlinks
- data-dump
- asking-questions
- recent-activity
- new-users
- profile-page
- flagging
- chat
- unanswered-questions
- retagging
- moderation
- data-explorer
- close-reasons
- user-accounts
- formatting
- interesting-tags
- up-votes
- meta
- statistics
- login
- rss
- favorites
- deleted-questions
- tagging
- votes
- tag-synonyms
- design

Plus, of course, the required and moderator-only tags. In addition to being pre-populated on the site, the list above is special in that none of those tags will ever be removed by the automatic cleanup logic.

Comment: Yes. I forget when/why this was changed, but internally - and in this old set of tags - they're still interesting.

Comment: `meta`, seriously?

Comment: Oops, I think I once killed `site-promotion` in favour of `promotion`. Didn't know the former was supposed to be the standard form. But thanks to this answer now I know.

Comment: Are some of these tags already synonyms of other ones or all of these standalone tags? (Especially when seeing `tags`, `tagging` and `retagging`, as well as `votes`, `voting`, `up-votes` and `down-votes`.)

Comment: None of them are synonyms, @ChristianRau.

Comment: @ChristianRau `tagging` and `tags` got synonymised on SFF meta; I guess things like that must have happened a lot. [tag:feature-request]: **give these automatically generated tags automatically generated tag wikis so it's clear how to use them**.

Comment: how 'bout you post that as an *actual feature-request*, eh @rand?

Comment: @Shog9 I figured it'd be a dupe as somebody must have thought of this before. If not, sure ... coming right up!