# Create automatic tag wikis for the automatic tags on per-site metas

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-wiki, per-site-meta

In an answer to [Which tags are automatically added to per-site metas?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277616/278659), I received a list of 53 tags, plus required and moderator-only tags, which are automatically added to every per-site meta when the site is created.

I don't know how many, if any, of these also get automatically generated tag wikis. My guess would be that the required and moderator-only tags do, but probably not any of the others. Even on reasonably large meta sites, many of these tags are missing their tag wikis. So my proposal is:

### automatically generate tag wikis for all the automatically generated tags.

This would make it much easier to administer these tags. As it is, some of them have been synonymised and merged, others have never been used, and the vast majority of them have no usage guidance (in the form of tag wikis and tag wiki excerpts) whatsoever.